# Segmentation Fault while reading parquet file from AWS S3 using read_parquet in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, fastparquet

I have a python script running on an AWS EC2 (on AWS Linux), and the scripts pulls a parquet file from S3 into Pandas dataframe. I'm now migrating to new AWS account and setting up a new EC2. This time when executing the same script on python virtual environment I get "Segmentation Fault" and the execution ends.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import s3fs
import boto3
from fastparquet import write
from fastparquet import ParquetFile

print("loading...")
df = pd.read_parquet('<my_s3_path.parquet>', engine='fastparquet')
```

All packages were imported and all S3 and AWS configurations were set.

when executing the full script I get:

```
loading...
Segmentation fault
```

As you can see not much to work with. I've been googling for a few hours and I saw many speculations and reasons for this symptom. I'll appreciate the help here.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by changing the used engine parameter. 
according to the official documentation of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html), those are the engine options:

> engine : {‘auto’, ‘pyarrow’, ‘fastparquet’}, default ‘auto’

so by just changing to 'auto', problem was solved.

```
df = pd.read_parquet('<my_s3_path.parquet>')
```

Comment: This works for me as well! Another solution, when you are loading multiple parquets in a loop is to put a print statement (could be empty). Probably a race condition somewhere

Comment: Another option I  recently found, if you use a virtual environment, try to remove it and re-create it using the most updated requirements.txt file. probably some of the dependencies messed-up